# How can I map a -1 to 1 range into 0 1?

Tags: functions, continuity

I've a range of values within the range $[-1, 1]$. But I need the same values transposed to values within the range $[0, 1]$. I don't talk about abs, but keeping the relationship/scale between them.

I'm using float vars, so I can deal with it without problem.

Comment: $\frac {x+1}{2}$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If all of your original values are in the range $[-1, 1]$, then adding $1$ to each value will translate the original values to the new range of $[0, 2]$.  Dividing each of the new values by $2$ will re-scale them to the final range $[0, 1]$.  So, in summary and as suggested by @lulu, if $x$ is in the range $[-1, 1]$, then $y=(x+1)/2$ will be in the range $[0, 1]$.

You mention scale in your question so note that the width of the interval $[0, 1]$ is half that of the interval $[-1, 1]$.  Further to get the original data into the new interval we had to divide by 2.  This implies that the transformed values will be on a different "scale" compared to the original values.  Specifically, using this scheme the transformed values will be only half as far apart as the values on the original scale.